# ¿Cómo convertir imágenes tiff con formato de compresión LZW a CCITT4?

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Tengo un problema con la conversión de una imagen en formato **TIFF** con compresión **LZW** a una compresión **CCITT4**.

El proyecto está hecho en Visual Studio 2005. Haciendo pruebas e investigando un poco, encontré que esto era posible utilizando las librerías de microsoft `System.Drawing`. Pero a la hora de probarlo, no funciona, arroja un error que dice "`Parameter is not valid`" a la hora de guardar la imágen.

Cabe mencionar que el error solo se presenta con el `encoder CCITT4`. Si pongo **LZW** funciona correctamente. Indagando un poco más, me encontré con que esto no es compatible con el sistema operativo (Windows Server 2003).

Comparto el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string fileOriginRoute = @"C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Imagenes\";
            string fileDestinationRoute = @"C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\ImagenesConvertidas\";
            string fileName = "Imagen.tif";
            Bitmap myBitmap;
            myBitmap = new Bitmap(fileOriginRoute + fileName);
            ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
            myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder;
            myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression;
            EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;
            myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
            myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
            try
            {
                myBitmap.Save(memStream, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.